# MySQL output in PHP table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I try to get data out of MySQL and show it in a PHP table but the sum_order is showing only in one row and all the other data are good. I don't find where did I go wrong with it.

Table structure

be table

| barcode | amount | date | user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R-001 | 10 | 2022-01-03 10:41:24 | 38 |

brikett_order table

| barcode | amount | date | costumer | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R-001 | 10 | 2022-01-03 10:41:24 | corp | zárt |

My code:

```
<div class="col-sm">
            <h5 class="mt-3">Havi Gyártás</h5>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Hónap</th>
                    <th scope="col">Munkanapok</th>
                    <th scope="col">Gyártás</th>
                    <th scope="col">Eladás</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $sql_list = 
                    "SELECT MONTH(date) AS month,   
                    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(date)) AS work_days, 
                    COUNT(*) AS sum_number
                    FROM be 
                    WHERE barcode='R-001'
                    GROUP BY month";
                    $result_list = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_list);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_list)) {  
                        ?>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?=$row['month']?></th>
                    <td><?=$row['work_days']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['sum_number']?>&nbsp;db</td>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    $sql_list = 
                    "SELECT MONTH(date) AS month,   
                    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(date)) AS work_days, 
                    SUM(amount) AS sum_order
                    FROM brikett_order 
                    WHERE barcode='R-001' AND state='zárt'
                    GROUP BY month";
                    $result_list = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_list);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_list)) {  
                        ?>
                    <td><?=$row['sum_order']?>&nbsp;db</td>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

The output table is like this:

| month | work_days | sum_number | sum_order |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 | 338 |  |  |
| 2 | 10 | 150 | 233 | 100 |

What I'am looking for:

| month | work_days | sum_number | sum_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 | 338 | 233 |
| 2 | 10 | 150 | 100 |

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to predict table links without table structure, but you could implement all in one query using JOIN or LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT MONTH(be.date) AS month,
COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(be.date)) AS work_days,
COUNT(be.date) AS sum_number,
SUM(bo.amount) AS sum_order 
FROM be
LEFT JOIN brikett_order bo on bo.state='zárt' and bo.barcode =  be.barcode and bo.date = be.date
WHERE be.barcode='R-001'
GROUP BY month
```

Then just create table rows at once:

```
 <tr>
   <th scope="row"><?=$row['month']?></th>
   <td><?=$row['work_days']?></td>
   <td><?=$row['sum_number']?>&nbsp;db</td>
   <td><?=$row['sum_order']?>&nbsp;db</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Thx! It looks good but no data in sum order only db. I have  ad it to my post the table structure

Comment: Hello! I checked it in MySQL and it says "No database selected"

Comment: You should select your database to run query. Write "USE your_db_name" before script.

Comment: Where to add USE?

Comment: You wrote, that you are checked it in MySQL. What is your MySQL checker?  Before run any script, you should select database where this script should be run. If you are running MySQL Workbench try to doubleclick on your database to make it bold. Then system would know "where" sciprt should be run.